# back lit banner DPI question

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, dpi

I need to have a banner printed for a back lit header on a shelving unit in a retail store with the following dimensions 2’-11" x 1’-0", how many DPI would you recommend printing at? 
Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere between 72dpi and 1200 dpi depending on:

- the type of art (photographic versus type)
- distance a typical person would be viewing it from
- quality/type of printer creating it.

300 is usually a safe bet, but we really can't give you any specific answer without knowing the details. I'd suggest talking to the vendor that is printing it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use resolution from 150-200 dpi depends on how far you would stand to look at it. If you have a vector file, you wouldn't have problem to enlarge it. However, you must consider your image source when you used raster image in your banner. Hope it could help!